# Django login doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration, email-validation

I have a problem with django login. I am using django's own login page but the problem is that when I register a new user, user cannot login. I have tried everything but couldn't find any resolutions. I can see the users name in my database.DB. Any idea for solving this problem?

My login form.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
   confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('username', 'email')
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserProfile
       fields = ('website', 'picture','user_type')
```

Error says: Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

So this means it can't find my user even though I can see them from database.

Comment: You should show how you are creating the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you do not have 'password' in your meta class. So you Meta class should look like:

class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake with handling authentication in Django is not processing the login form correctly in your view; namely, using the **authenticate** and **login** functions provided by Django properly. These are *required* in order to properly authenticate users; **authenticate** creates a hash of the password to check against the encrypted password in the database, and **login** sets up the session data that marks the current user as logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

If you feel you are properly using these functions in your view, then please post the code you are using for your view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `django.contrib.auth.views`

example:`urls.py`

`from django.contrib.atuh import views as auth_views
 url(r'^login/' , auth_views.login , {'template_name' : 'path/to/template.html'} , name='login')`

that's it, just use the `{{form}}` variable in `path/to/template.html`

[DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: Thank you for comment but that wasn't the issue.